# How to filter query by pair of foreign keys in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, foreign-keys

I have huge problem with writing one query using Django. My model (only important part of it - relations) looks like that:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)

class Topic(models.Model):
    create_user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Post(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

It represents objects for forum application. I need to write query that returns user who is most active commentator - highest post count in topics he did not create. In SQL it would look like this:

```
select user_id, count(*) 
from forum_app_post post 
inner join forum_app_topic topic on topic.id = post.topic_id 
where post.user_id != topic.create_user_id 
group by user_id;
```

Hard part for me is filtering posts by 'post.user_id != topic.create_user_id' in Django. I get exceptions when i try to use two fields in one filter and i was unable to find any kind of workaround using Django. I don't want to use raw SQL (using Cursor object).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
Post.objects.exclude(user=F('topic__user')).values('user').annotate(Count('id'))
```

The [F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.F) allows self-reference for querysets, thus we are excluding posts that have the same user as their topic's creator. Then we just group by user_id.